# Adding Custom pricing and name in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

i am new to the magento and i have a small problem. Suppose, while entering the order from backend the admin has to add a product which doesn\’t exist in his shop. So, does he have to first add the product and then again enter the order or is there a simple way of doing it from the order page?? I don\’t want to save the product. I just want to take the order and enter it without adding the product with its price. Please Help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no feature like this in Magento and to be honest it is kind of a bizarre situation you are describing. Although Magento does not keep a reference to product tables in sales flat order item table but having an item in this table which we can find no history about it anywhere else is quite unconventional in e-commerce solutions. However in your case you should develop a module which adds these kind of products directly to the order items and handles financial issues concerning these products.